# Android Fragment and Listview adapter issue

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I've created an fragment `unity_view` which contains a listView :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewUnity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstName" >
</ListView>
```

The following code (the class extends Fragment) generate an null exception:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
    // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
    // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }

    final ListView listview = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewUnity);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
        "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
        "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
      list.add(values[i]);
    }
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.unity_view, container, false);
}
```

Two questions:

1. Do you know why the `listview.setAdapter` failed?
2. Should I not include the **listViewUnity** as a choice in `android.R.layout`?

Answer (score 0):

First you can't find `android.R.layout.listViewUnity` because `android.R.layout` are internal android layouts that you can't modify. Instead you access your own layouts with `R.layout.listViewUnity`.

Second your `ListView` is located in your fragment's layout (unity_view.xml). To access it 
from code it first needs to be inflated:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unity_view, container, false);
final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewUnity);
// Do something else

return layout;
```

Finally when you're creating the adapter pass the activity as the context together with your items along so they are populated in the list:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the `ListView` from the `Activity`, but it is in the layout of your `Fragment`. Try this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unity_view, container, false);

   final ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewUnity);
   // Do something with your ListView

   return view;
```

}

As far as I know, there is no `listViewUnity` layout in the Android SDK.

Comment: Yes, it was a custom list. Thanks!